# Ruby on Rails - etc/hosts config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, hosts

This is what I have in my "etc/hosts" file:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1 gotqn-System-Product-Name
>
> 127.0.0.1     depot.yourhost.com

and this is what I have added in the apache2.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName depot.yourhost.com

   DocumentRoot "/home/gotqn/Aptana Projects/depot/public/"

   <Directory "/home/gotqn/Aptana Projects/depot/public">

      AllowOverride all

      Options -MultiViews

      Order allow,deny

      Allow from all

   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I type **http://localhost/** my browser lists all my files in the "var\www" folder and when I type **http://depot.yourhost.com/** it displays the following error:

> **We're sorry, but something went wrong.**

I have checked the production.log file of my rails applications and it says:

> Connecting to database specified by database.yml
>
> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-13 20:32:41 +0200 Processing
>   by StoreController#index as HTML Completed 500 Internal Server Error
>   in 3ms
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'carts'):
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:46:in `rescue in
>   current_cart'   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:44:in`
>   current_cart'   app/controllers/store_controller.rb:11:in `index'

I suppose that there is something wrong with my database configuration as the table exists but it is not found.

Anyway, my questions is how the hosts file knew that "depot.yourhost.com" means to open the rails applications and "localhost" do list my "var\www" folder - I have thought that RoR is using port 3000.

Why there is no conflict for port 80?

Comment: Looks like you have mod_passenger running in Apache?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, correct. That's what I am using - passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails applications run under port 3000 when running with the lightweight Webrick server.  Since you are running Apache with mod_passenger, the application will be available at port 80 according to your Apache configuration.

The hosts file contains an entry `127.0.0.1 depot.yourhost.com` which directs that domain name to your local adapter 127.0.0.1. The hosts file should always be checked before a nameserver needs to be consulted to retrieve a name's address.

Next, your Apache configuration includes a `VirtualHost` which is listening on *all* network adapters due to the `*` in

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Your Apache configuration must be setup to use name-based virtual hosting, after which the `ServerName` variable is matched against the `HTTP_HOST` request header which was supplied by your request to `depot.yourhost.com`.

Therefore, you can have as many `VirtualHost`s as needed all using port 80 on the same IP address, and Apache will decide which to route the request to based on the `HTTP_HOST` header.

Finally, mod_passenger will detect if an application is a Ruby on Rails application by inspecting the directory contents around the `DocumentRoot` which you have specified in the VirtualHost configuration. If it finds the `public` directory as its `DocumentRoot` and a RoR application at a level higher, Passenger will attempt to start the Rails app.

Now, as to why you are getting a directory listing from `localhost`... Elsewhere in your Apache configuration you must have a `VirtualHost` which matches the `ServerName localhost` and sets its `DocumentRoot` to `/vart/www`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  # or...
  ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are seeing the contents of the directory listed out rather than a `403 Forbidden` (absent an index file like `index.html`), it is because the Apache server config or `VirtualHost` config does *not* include the directive:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Add that in the global `httpd.conf` to prevent listing directories server-wide.

Comment: @Thanks a lot for the detail answer. Could you give a good tutorial about how to config these files using RoR+ Apache +passenger and if I have not specified the "ServerName localhost" in my Apache config file, where this could be specified?

Comment: @gotqn To find why it is routing to /var/www, look for `DocumentRoot /var/www` possibly in the main Apache config httpd.conf or apache2.conf. An unmatched ServerName in any other VirtualHost probably routes to the global DocumentRoot.

Comment: As for tutorials, I don't really have one to point you to. I'm familiar with Apache config just having been a sysadmin for several years, and I find [the Passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) to be pretty thorough, even though they aren't easy to navigate.